# Displaying a list of current parameters on error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, debugging, reporting

In my program I have a method that is called every time a try catch statement catches an exception that takes in the exception and sends me an email with the error stack trace, who was logged in, and which computer name had the issue. I am looking for a way to have it include all the current code variables, including global variables, so I can accurately recreate the issue by knowing everything the user passed in. I know when the code is debugging you can see variables in the bottom corner of visual studio or you can hover your mouse over the variable to see the value. Is there anyway to get a list of all variables and their current value while the code is deployed and running on someone's PC?
[Variable Section of Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfnMi.png)

Comment: Might be worth investigating some of the 3rd party logging tools already around that do all this for you.  Saves re-inventing the wheel so to speak

Comment: I'd suggest looking into memory dumps.  If you can get a dump file, you can load it in a debugger and recapture the user's memory state.  It's not necessarily trivial to work with, though... I'm not sure the capabilities of the Visual Studio debugger, and WinDbg is powerful but not particularly user-friendly.